# Prototype "this" not working (JS)

Tags: javascript, canvas, prototype-programming

Trying to do an .onload method with an Image() object and apparently it isn't inheriting the "this" in its function. Any help?

```
function UI() {
    this.canvas_obj = document.getElementById('game');
    this.canvas = this.canvas_obj.getContext('2d');
    this.imgcache = {};
    this.imglist = [
        'rooms/main-square.png'
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.imglist.length ; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = this.imglist[i];
        this.imgcache[this.imglist[i]] = img;
    }
}

// snip //

/*
 * drawImg
 * Draws an image on the canvas at the specified x, y (if the image isn't in the pre-cache, it creates it as well)
 * @param str   image path
 * @param array x,y
 * @param array width, height
 */
UI.prototype.drawImg = function(path, coords, size) {
    var found = false;
    if (size == undefined) {
        var w = 0;
        var h = 0;
    } else {
        var w = size[0];
        var h = size[1];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.imgcache.length ; i++) {
        if (path == this.imgcache[i].src) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = path;
        this.imgcache[path] = img;
    }
    if (w == 0 && h == 0) {
        this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
            this.canvas.drawImage(this.imgcache[path], coords[0], coords[1], this.imgcache[path].width, this.imgcache[path].height);
        };
    } else {
        this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
            this.canvas.drawImage(this.imgcache[path], coords[0], coords[1], w, h);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: One other point in your code.  If you're expecting onload to always get called for an image, you have to set the onload handler before you set `.src` because onload may fire immediately when you set `.srv` if the image is coming from the browser cache.

Answer (score 3):

As for every variable, in JavaScript, the scope of `this` is relative to function you are in. So, when in

```
this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
     // ...   
};
```

`this` will be bound to the object `imgcache[path]`. A common approach is to keep the value of `this` in another variable (by convention, it's often `that`) in order to access it inside nested functions: it's called a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

```
var that = this;

this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
     // that will reference the "outer this"
};
```

---

Now, this is due to how JavaScript binds the `this` value on function invocation. It is possible to bind `this` to another value by using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: For sake of completion, it's worth mentioning bind (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: The value of a function's *this* keyword has **nothing** to do with scope. It is controlled **only** by how a function is called (except for ES5 bind, but that can be ignored for now).

Comment: @RobG Since JavaScript has only function scope for variables, I think it's the easiest way to explain how binding works without going into the subtleties of the language.

Comment: *this* is always bound to the current execution context (function or global). Probably just quibbling over words, but if you want to keep it simple, don't mention scope at all in relation to *this*.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a function's *this* keyword is set by how the function is called. When the *drawImg* method is called on an instance of UI, e.g.:

```
var fooUI = new UI(...);
fooUI.drawImg(...);
```

then in the method *fooUI.drawImg*, the *this* keyword will reference *fooUI*.

Within the method there is an assignment to an *onload* property:

```
    this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
        this.canvas.drawImage(this.imgcache[path], coords[0], coords[1],
                              this.imgcache[path].width, this.imgcache[path].height);
    };
```

The first *this* will reference *fooUI*. However, the anonymous function assigned to the *onload* property is called as a method of the object referenced by *this.imagecache[path]*, so that is the object referenced by the function's *this* when called.

You can change that by using a closure to a local variable with a sensible name (*that* is not a good choice in my opinion) like:

```
    var uiObj = this;
    this.imgcache[path].onload = function() {
        uiObj.canvas.drawImage(uiObj.imgcache[path], coords[0], coords[1],
                               uiObj.imgcache[path].width, uiObj.imgcache[path].height);
    };
```